# What is the accessibility level of select2 and can I get VPAT document for select2?

Tags: accessibility, jquery-select2, wcag, wcag2.0

Recently my firm asked to get accessibility status of all 3rd party content we are using. I can see active and closed issues on github regarding accessibility in select2 library, but is select2 formally compliant with wcag guidelines (web content accessibility guidelines) .If yes then what level? (WCAG 2.x A/AA/AAA)
Is there a VPAT(voluntary product accessibility template) document provided by select2 which I can use(can't find it in anywhere-github/docs)?
It is demanded from teams to get VPAT documents of all 3rd party content.
Is there a forum or a person or a place where I can request accessibility status / vpat document for select2.

Comment: select2's accessibility is rather bad. I tried it using Android's TalkBack and it's almost impossible to make a selection. This includes version 4.1.0-rc0 which supposedly contains accessibility improvements.

Answer (score 1):

You should raise this question on the [select2 repository](https://github.com/select2/select2). Judging by the number of open accessibility issues, it’s not likely that it will meet a high level of compliance.